# Unable to modify the QGIS project CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Using QGIS 2.18.3, I have a project containing a single vector layer.  Both the project and the layer have the same CRS: NAD83/Alaska Albers (EPSG:3338).  I need to temporarily modify the project's CRS by changing the Longitude of Center from the default value of -154 to -163.

I've tried to edit the default longitude value in the Project Properties window, as highlighted in the screenshot below, but QGIS does not allow me to overwrite the default value.

[image]

Please note that I do not wish to reproject the data layer; rather I wish to modify the project display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to modify an existing CRS, then go to `Settings -> Custom CRS -> Click on Copy Existing button` located at the lower right corner, as shown below:

[image]

Search for `EPSG: 3338`to modify the Longitude of Center from the default value of -154 to -163.

Lastly, you need to modify the name of existing CRS as below (for example):

[image]

Now go to `Project -> Project Properties` and enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation if it is not enabled already, and navigate to `User defined CRS` located at the bottom of CRS list to select the CRS that you modified in the previous step:

[image]