# changing projection in QGIS 3.0 not working?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.0 and trying to modify the projection. For some reason, it's not allowing me to change to a user defined projection, it only allows me to select one of the previously defined projections, or previously defined user projections. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to modify the QGIS project CRS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234585/unable-to-modify-the-qgis-project-crs)